# Sokoban Java for Uni

Tags: java

my task for the university is to make an sokoban game in Java.
Its not a big task, just the field, the player in position X=0 Y=0 and the mechanic to move him around.
I'm totally new to java and I dont know how to put a player in the field.
This is all i have until now:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sokoban {

public static void main(String[] args) {

char[][] room = new char[8][4];


for(int y=0; y<4; y++){
    for(int x=0; x<8; x++){
        room[x][y]= '.';

    }
}

for(int y=0; y<4; y++){
    for(int x=0; x<8; x++){
        System.out.print(room[x][y]); 
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
}
```

and yes the field is just a bunch of points.
any help is appreciated

Comment: Think about the methods you need: e.g. something to draw the field, something that reads input from the keyboard, something that updates the field based on the input, some check if the game should be terminated. Arrange those methods and then try to make java code out of it...

Comment: Do u have any advise how to make a player? the field is already there and i think i can do the rest alone

Answer (score 0):

Here's on how you could create a Player on your field:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){               
    for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
        room[i][j]='.'; 
        if (i==0 &&j==0) {
            room[0][0]='P';
            }
        System.out.print(room[i][j]+" ");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: don't forget to add a Scanner to your game, so you can "read" the actions of the player and use them!

Comment: thank u guys, already got a Scanner. if i dont know how to move the player until tomorrow i will ask more "stupid" questions :)